# why javax.servlet.context.tempdir not working in apache tomcat 8.0.14

Tags: tomcat, servlets, struts2

I am hosting `struts2` application on `linux os`

In `struts.xml` specified below code for file upload but not creating `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` folder on VPS server

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="javax.servlet.context.tempdir" />
```

what is the issue?

```
Tomcat version used- Apache Tomcat 8.0.14.

OS used for hosting- linux
jdk version- jdk1.8.0_20
```

Help me to solve this problem

Comment: My code in struts.xml    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="javax.servlet.context.tempdir" />

Comment: I'd assume because it's using the value precisely as you give it, and not evaluating it in any way.

Comment: Then what is the solution ?